# Dynamically loading service providers

Tags: module, laravel-4, hmvc

I am creating an application with a control panel for three different versions of a server, and they may have different database layouts (that's the reason I am modularizing). I am following [this tutorial](http://creolab.hr/2013/05/modules-in-laravel-4/).

How can I, dynamically, load only the service provider of the corrent server version? Every version has it's own folder, and the version chosen is stored is accessible with Config::get, is it already loaded when the service providers are loaded?

Also, if I use the HMVC architecture, can I still use the default folders (not modules) for application-wide, server-common controllers? (like news, which are not server-dependent).

If I didn't make myself clear, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you cannot dinamically load a Service Provider without doing something odd in your code, but Service Providers are class loaders themselves and you should be using one Service Provider to load, dynamically, your services:

```
<?php

class ServiceProvider extends Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('server', function($app) {

            switch ($this->app['config']['serverVersion']) {
                case 'versionX':
                    return new ServiceClassForServerX();
                    break;

                case 'versionY':
                    return new ServiceClassForServerY();
                    break;

                default:
                    return new ServiceClassForDefaultServer();
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array('sever');
    }

}
```

About folders, Laravel gives you 100% freedom to choose whatever folder structure you want to use in `app/*`.

Comment: Fine, I already made some service providers dependent on configuration before, this was a piece of cake. The problem is that I have a generic header/footer that create links to some routes I only define on the specific routes.php (although all servers do have to implement those routes, such as account.create). I then get `Route [account.create] not defined.` even though `php artisan routes` report the `accounts.create` route as existing.

Comment: For example, I have a link to create a new account that points to `account.create`, on every page if the user is logged out. Do I have to hard-code the link?